# AttributeError: 'ExcelFile' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I was trying to remove the empty column in an excel file using pandas using dropna() method. But I ended up with the above error message. Please find my code below :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile("1.xlsx")

print(df.sheet_names)

#df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)

newdf = df.dropna()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you tried, 'read_excel' Since, ExcelFile is a class and read_excel is a function

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more code and context, but this might help:

```py
import pandas as pd

excel_file_name = 'insert excel file path'
excel_sheet_name = 'insert sheet name'

# create dataframe from desired excel file
df = pd.read_excel(
    excel_file_name,
    engine='openpyxl',
    sheet_name=excel_sheet_name
)
# drop columns with NaN values and write that into df 
# # without the inplace option it would have to be 
# < df = df.dropna(axis=1) >
df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True) 

# write that dataframe to excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter(
    excel_file_name, # file to write to
    engine='openpyxl', # which engine to use
    mode='a', # use mode append (has to be used for if_sheet_exists to work)
    if_sheet_exists='replace' # if that sheet exists, replace it
) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=excel_sheet_name)
```